# how to set automatic proxy scripts for git?

Tags: git, proxy

Is it possible to use an automatic script as git's proxy?

I'm using `http://xxx/yyy` as my IE proxy, where `xxx` is a host and `yyy` is a javascript file which returns a proxy or "DIRECT" depends on different situations.
The script is rather complicated (more than 300 lines and maintained by the corporate IT deparmentt).

Edit:
My real problem: is if I am in corporate network I use a proxy for external sites, and "DIRECT" for corporate sites.  Otherwise I'd use "DIRECT".

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget that you [set a proxy per Git repo url](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18712501/6309)

That means if your script criteria for attributing a proxy url is only: "if github.com then use this proxy", you don't need the script at all:

```
git config --global http."https://github.com".proxy http://mydomain\\myusername:mypassword@myproxyserver:proxyport
```

> I use a proxy for external sites, and "DIRECT" for corporate sites.

For Git, all you need to do is define the environment variable

```
NO_PROXY=.mycompany.com,.sock,localhost,127.0.0.1
```

That is enough for git to *not* use a proxy when cloning a repo hosted by your company, as opposed to one hosted on the internet.

Comment: The problem is that it's not simple. The js code is more than 300 lines.

Comment: @LeonZeng do you mean that for github.com (for instance), the script could return different proxy url?

Comment: Thanks Von. It's still not what I wanted. What I want is something like "No proxy when I am not connected to a VPN".

Comment: @LeonZeng You can't detect a VPN connection (http://stackoverflow.com/q/33300877/6309), so a simple script to switch proxy settings on demand (ie launched by you) seems easier.

Comment: Yes that's feasible, but it's tricky to switch it frequently.