# Stripe Integration: Show price based on users location

Tags: node.js, reactjs, stripe-payments

I am using React.JS as Front end and Node.JS as Backend. I have to integrate Stripe Payment Gateway. As per the requirement, I have to show the price based on users location.

For example, if the user is from USA then I have to show $100 but if someone is from Africa then I have to show $50. All the users will be able to use the same content no matter from where they are accessing the website.

The tricky part here is, if someone uses VPN and changes the location then the system should restrict such user.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can refer to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33300877/how-do-you-detect-a-vpn-or-proxy-connection), if you want to detect the user's location and proxy. [ipinfo.io](https://ipinfo.io) offers you to detect location and proxy. I am not sure if this can be implemented in the backend because I couldn't find the user's ip from the request param, that is why I have implemented it on the frontend side.

After accessing user's ip and making request to the [ipinfo.io](https://ipinfo.io), you can pass the user's location while requesting the payment intent from the backend. To create payment intent you can refer to [this doc](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents/create)